# Question about proof that $(a + b)^p = a^p+b^p$ in a field of characteristic $p$.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Definition charactersitic $p$: a field has characterstic $p$ is its prime field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

**Proposition:** let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p$. Then for any $a, b \in K$ we have $(a + b)^p = a^p + b^p$.

**Proof:** (from my text) because $p \choose i$ is divisible by $p$ for $0 < 1 < p$ it is zero $\mod p$, so $p \choose i$  $a^{p - i}b^i$ is zero (this is the part I don't understand), so it follows from Newton's binomial law.

I understand that the prime field of $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so if $a, b$ are in the prime field, then $p \choose i$  $a^{p - i}b^i$ is zero, but that is not necessarily the case is it?

Comment: If $K$ has characteristic $p$, then $p\cdot a = 0$ for every $a\in K$.

Comment: @Exodd that's not the way it was defined in my text, see the edited OP. Are those definition equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your definition, the prime field of $K$ is $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. Let $1$ be the identity element in $K$, $1_p$ the identity element in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and let
$$\varphi: \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\to K$$
be a field immersion.

We know that $\varphi$ is injective, meaning that the counterimage of 0 is only $0_p$. This means that $\varphi(1_p)$ is invertible in $K$ and
$$
\varphi(1_p) = \varphi(1_p \cdot 1_p) = \varphi(1_p)\varphi(1_p) \implies \varphi(1_p) = 1.
$$
Given any $a\in K$, the sum of $p$ copies of $a$ is
$$ a + \dots + a = (1 + \dots + 1)a = (\varphi(1_p) + \dots + \varphi(1_p)) a = \varphi(1_p + \dots + 1_p)a = \varphi(0) a = 0.$$
This means that the sum of $p$ copies of $a$ yields zero.

Since $\binom pi$ is a multiple of $p$, then if $x\in K$, you have
$$\binom pix = p(..) x = 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the definition of "characteristic $p$". This mean essentially that $p=0$ in $\mathbb{K}$. Well, if $p=0$, then $pk=0$ for any $k\in \mathbb{K}$. Since $p|$${p}\choose{i}$, then ${p}\choose{i}$ $=pm=0$ for some $m\in \mathbb{K}$.

Comment: that's not the way it was defined in my text, see the edited OP. Are those definition equivalent?

Comment: They are: of course your definition imply mine. If you have my definition, the set $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1 \}$ is a field( you can check by definition) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
The prime field is the intersection of all fields, right? Well, so the prime field $\mathbb{K}_0$ of $\mathbb{K}$ is such that $\mathbb{K}_0\subset \mathbb{Z}_p$. But $ \mathbb{Z}_p$ doesn't have any proper subfield, so $\mathbb{K}_0=\mathbb{Z}_p$.